# Setting height of ImageView programmatically with data from MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, imageview, android-glide

I have a problem about setting hight of imageView in Android Studio. I take image from MySQL using Glide.
When I use height "wrap_content", the row without image value it can work well but the row with image value work badly because the image fill almost all the screen. When I set the height with static value (200dp) it work badly for row with null value.
I use the code below but it can't solve my problem.

```
if (image.equals("")){
        int dimensionInDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 0, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        postImage.getLayoutParams().height = dimensionInDp;
        postImage.requestLayout(); }  else {
        int dimensionInDps = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        postImage.getLayoutParams().height = dimensionInDps;
        postImage.requestLayout();}
```

result of the code is all the imageview set height to 200dp.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use [ImageView.setScaleType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) and leave the ImageView width and height in wrap_content. That will let the image to auto fit the ImageView (FIT_CENTER) or to be cropped (CENTER_CROP)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying minHeight in imageView in your xml file.
like this:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:minHeight="200dp"
     android:src="@drawable/imageView"/>
```